# How to load in columns of data automatically as variables in r

Tags: r

I have a data set which has over 100 variables/column headers and I want to load all of them as variables into R. I can load the dataset in fine, but I find it tedious having to convert each column as :

```
var1 <- df$col1 
var2 <- df$col2 
...
```

all the way to `var100 <- df$col100`. How can I quickly make all of these columns turn into variables?

Bonus points for saying how to only get certain columns turn into variables quickly, such as columns 5 through 85.

I know I should also post a usable data frame or something for a person answering to download and manipulate but I don't know how to get my data frame in R into my StackOverflow question so I only have an example 5x5 grid image of the data in excel to provide. Again this is a far larger dataset than the image shows.

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJEW5.png)

Comment: It is not recommended.  `list2env(setNames(df, paste0('var', seq_along(df))), .GlobalEnv)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also do it with `assign()`:

```r
dat <- data.frame(
  var1 = rnorm(10), 
  var2 = rnorm(10), 
  var3 = rnorm(10), 
  var4 = rnorm(10), 
  var5 = rnorm(10)
)

for(i in 1:ncol(dat)){
  assign(paste0("var", i), dat[[paste0("var", i)]])
}
var1
#>  [1] -0.98086606  0.40048599  1.19099096  1.03191817 -1.06956025 -0.03919399
#>  [7]  1.32809944  1.05396682  0.07826412  1.00137558
var2
#>  [1] -0.37338283  0.48710182  0.80729920  0.98664978  0.06286747  2.77966983
#>  [7] -0.08503804 -0.17249172  0.88482571 -0.83201587
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

This also makes it easy to only do some columns by changing the numbers over which the loop operates (e.g., `1:ncol(dat)` could be something like `c(1,3,7,12)` or `5:85`).

Comment: What if I have more complicated variable names I want to assign, such as var1 being apples and var2 being oranges, which are already listed in the dataframe column headers?

Comment: You could use `assign(names(df)[i], df[[i]])` if you just want to assign the columns to their column name in the global environment.

Comment: do you have suggestions about how I can then use that list of variables we create in a loop to run a formula using each of the variables? For example I want apples, then oranges, then bananas and so on to be piped into the formula "model=gam(price~s(apples,k=2)" and save the output of each of the models and automatically compiles each of the model summaries into a table?

Comment: @PatrickRoney this is basically an entirely different question (or perhaps 2 entirely different questions).  You should post this question separately with an example of some data that could be used.